# Not able to append the value at specific place with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some code of Javscript, which is used to get the HTML markup or text data from user and submit it server.

Now I put a dialogue box that will collection the description about the code from user on button click and it also sends the data to server as description.

So I need all thing together in a structured coding.

If user is putting some HTML code inside textarea and try to save it, the program will ask for description and once user enter it, the description should be saved exactly before the closing of body tag.

I have tried to add the string with textarea value but it add the string at last of the code, I mean after closing of HTMl Tag. I need it before closing of body tag.

HTML code is

```
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="makePage()">Save this code</a>
```

The Javascript Code

```
<script>

    function makePage(){
    var titlename = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value;

    var comment = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value  += '<p>' + description + '</p>';
    alert (comment);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
    }
    var content = JSON.stringify({ comment: comment, titlename: titlename, description: description});
    xmlhttp.open("POST","makePage.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(content);
    }

</script>
```

And finally the PHP code

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$content = $data['comment'];
$description = $data['descriptionname'];
$finalcontent = $content . $description;
$title = $data['titlename'];
$file = trim($title).".html";
file_put_contents("userdata/$file", $finalcontent);
echo $file;
?>
```

I need someone who can put this variable description exactly before closing of body tag.

Please check it here : https://html5andcss3.org/tryit_2.php

You can write some code in the left side and hit Run. This will give you some output then try to save it from save icon and it will ask you for title and description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the following javascript, I don't see any jQuery code so I think you just want to append text after the function is called:

```
function makePage(){
var titlename = "title";
var description = "description";

var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
paragraph.innerHTML = description;
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].append(paragraph);
var comment = paragraph.outerHTML;
alert (comment);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
}
var content = JSON.stringify({ comment: comment, titlename: titlename, description: description});
xmlhttp.open("POST","makePage.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(content);
}`
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].append(paragraph);

I think this line will call first existence of body tag. and I will append in main page. I need this inside textarea.
please see the given link of working code, I have updated. You can see the problem

Comment: The description does a[[end as text in  your code, so you want to append the tag itself inside the textarea? if so, I think it isn't possible.

Comment: My code works and it can add the value with textarea value but it add at last of the code. I need if it can find somehow the element name and then put the code

Comment: @user3030404 you could replace text area with `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`, check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6a4q0jmn/)

Comment: So want to put it under the text area tag? You could always use the DOM methods to locate and append the HTML element